# Decode picture from Microsoft SQL Server "Image" type

Tags: python, sql-server, image

I am trying to decode one image stored in one column of type "Image" in 
Mirosoft SQL Server.

I access this column from python code via pyodbc with "ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server" drivers and what I get is this:

http://textuploader.com/d03ml

According to this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/ntext-text-and-image-transact-sql it is stored internally as unicode ucs-2 format.

I've tried decoding the huge string stored in the column as "utf-16" as in many places it is said to be equivalent to ucs-2(is it?). But the output string is never recognized as image (either by using Image class or any online image converter..)

Does anybody have some idea?

Comment: The `image` data type will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using this data type in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use it. Use `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

I found it out myself. Maybe it's useful for someone else.

The column holding the picture in SQL Server was a string compressed using the C# Deflate algorithm.

In python I used zlib.decompress(image_string[4:], -15).

the -15 indicates that the string to be decompressed has no header. I do that to prevent header check.

the [4:] indicates that the string starts from position 4 forwards (skipping the header, which is in the first 4 positions).

Then I got the raw string that could be easily read as image.

Comment: Can you help me with a little bit more detail how to save the decompressed something to a file? I try it but...

`image = zlib.decompress(string_from_db[4:], -15)`  

`    text_file = open("Output.txt", "w")`
`    text_file.write(image)`
`    text_file.close()`

Comment: why do you use such extension ("Output.txt") ? you should know the original extension of the image format and save it with that format.

Comment: For example, if it's a .png image just do open("Output.png", "w")